# DbContext is Null when call in primary constructor EF Core on .NET 8

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, masstransit, .net-8.0

I'm using .NET 8, my `DbContext` is null when call in primary constructor, but when call in normal constructor.

This is my `DbContext`:

```cs
public class DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : DbContext(options)
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public DbTSet<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.AddInboxStateEntity();
        builder.AddOutboxMessageEntity();
        builder.AddOutboxStateEntity();

        builder.Ignore<BaseEntity>();
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new())
    {
        foreach (var entity in ChangeTracker
                     .Entries()
                     .Where(x => x is { Entity: BaseEntity, State: EntityState.Modified })
                     .Select(x => x.Entity)
                     .Cast<BaseEntity>())
            entity.UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

My controller:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SubjectsController(DataContext context, IMapper mapper) : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{room}")]
    [Authorize]
    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<SubjectDto>> GetByRoom(string room)
    {
        var userId = Guid.Parse(User.GetObjectId());
        
        var students = await context.Students.OrderBy(x => x.StudentCode).ToListAsync();

        var student = await context.Students.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);
        
        if (student == null) 
            return NotFound("Student not found");

        var now = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow);
        var subject = await context.Subjects
            .Include(x => x.Students)
            .AsSplitQuery()
            .Where(x => x.Students.Contains(student))
            .ProjectTo<SubjectDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x =>
                x.Room.Equals(room, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                && x.DateStart <= now && now <= x.DateEnd
                && !x.IsEnded);
        
        if (subject == null) 
            return NotFound("Subject not found");

        return subject;
    }
}
```

When I execute:

- With primary constructor

  [image: With primary constructor]
- With normal constructor

  [image: With normal constructor]

I want `DbContext` to be not null when I call the primary constructor

UPDATED:

My Program.cs:

```cs
using ApplicationBase.Extensions;
using MassTransit;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Polly;
using StudentService.Consumers;
using StudentService.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
        services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddIdentityService(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
);

builder.Services.AddMassTransit(opts =>
{
    opts.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<DataContext>(opt =>
    {
        opt.QueryDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        opt.UseSqlServer();
        opt.UseBusOutbox();
    });

    opts.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<StudentAuthConsumer>();

    opts.SetEndpointNameFormatter(new KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter("student-svc", false));

    opts.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseMessageRetry(r =>
        {
            r.Handle<RabbitMqConnectionException>();
            r.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        });

        cfg.Host(builder.Configuration["RabbitMQ:Host"], "/", host =>
        {
            host.Username(builder.Configuration.GetValue("RabbitMQ:Username", "guest"));
            host.Password(builder.Configuration.GetValue("RabbitMQ:Password", "guest"));
        });

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseApplicationIdentity();
app.MapControllers();

var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .WaitAndRetry(5, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

retryPolicy.ExecuteAndCapture(() => app.InitDb());

app.Run();
```

Controller with normal constructor in 2nd image:

```cs
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using StudentService.Data;
using StudentService.DTOs;
using StudentService.Models;

namespace StudentService.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SubjectsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public SubjectsController(DataContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet("{room}")]
    [Authorize]
    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<SubjectDto>> GetByRoom(string room)
    {
        var userId = Guid.Parse(User.GetObjectId());

        if (!await _context.Students.AnyAsync(x => x.Id == userId))
            return NotFound("Student not found");

        var dateTimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var dateNow = DateOnly.FromDateTime(dateTimeNow);

        var subject = await _context.Subjects
            .AsSplitQuery()
            .Include(x => x.Students)
            .Where(x => x.Students.Any(s => s.Id == userId))
            .Include(x => x.Lessons)
            .Where(x => x.Lessons.Any(l => l.StartTime <= dateTimeNow && dateTimeNow <= l.EndTime))
            .ProjectTo<SubjectDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x =>
                x.Room.ToLower().Contains(room.ToLower())
                && x.DateStart <= dateNow && dateNow <= x.DateEnd
                && !x.IsEnded
            );

        if (subject == null) return NotFound("Subject not found");

        return subject;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<SubjectDto>> Create(SubjectCreateDto subjectCreateDto)
    {
        var userId = Guid.Parse(User.GetObjectId());

        if (!await _context.Teachers.AnyAsync(x => x.Id == userId))
            return NotFound("Teacher not found");

        var subject = _mapper.Map<Subject>(subjectCreateDto);
        subject.Students.Add(new Student { Id = userId });

        await _context.Subjects.AddAsync(subject);

        var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

        if (!result) return BadRequest();

        return _mapper.Map<SubjectDto>(subject);
    }
}
```

My packages:

- Main service:
  [image: Main service]
- Base service:
  [image: Base service]

Comment: Do you have a full runnable [mre]? Can you post it somewhere like github? Does this actually result in NRE thrown when running the code?

Comment: On the screenshots, one access "context" and the other "_context". But since I can't see the full code, I'm not able to say if this difference is important.

Comment: @Fildor: looks like just the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase` to me. The usual class you inherit when implementing the webapi.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Jepp, may be. I think I got confused because I didn't see it in the second snippet, but it just may be outside of the shot.

Comment: @heringer yes, because in the first case the primary ctor parameter is used (C# 12 feature) and in the second "ordinary" field assigned from the ctor. Both should work in this case (basically the primary ctors feature was designed to reduce such boilerplate code).

Comment: In general, this should work, in both cases. The request for a minimal reproducible example makes sense if we are supposed to help here.

Comment: Where does `AddOutboxMessageEntity` come from? MassTransit? Which version? How are the services and DataContext registered? The problem may be caused by MassTransit, or a missing registration.

Comment: @GuruStron here is a sample repo https://github.com/realShinchoku/DemoPrimaryCtorIsNull

Comment: @WiktorZychla it actually works. It is just debug view issue when primary ctor parameter is used in async method.

Comment: Hi @WiktorZychla,You can try to run this code in visual studio 17.9 preview 2.1 which has been solved such debugging view issue.

Comment: Thank to both of you, I know it works, I validated it locally after the question has been posted. That's why I joined the request for the reproducible example. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in debug view both in Rider and Visual Studio:

- [RIDER-102834 Evaluating primary constructor's fields works wrong in async/iterator methods](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-102834/Evaluating-primary-constructors-fields-works-wrong-in-async-iterator-methods) YouTrack issue.
- [Primary constructor variable null in debugger](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/70730) issue @github.

Based on the provided repro (after some changes to setup) the primary constructor is working fine. Changed `GetByRoom` method to the following:

```
// var userId = Guid.Parse(User.GetObjectId());

var userId = Guid.NewGuid();
if (!await context.Students.AnyAsync(x => x.Id == userId))
{
    var isNull = context is null;
    Console.WriteLine(isNull);
    var localCopy = context; // for debug view
    return NotFound("Student not found");
}
```

As shown on the following screenshots the `isNull` is `false` and `localCopy` displays correct value:

[image]

[image]

Comment: so it seems the service is not null, but the editor cannot display it, right? But why it displays the service if I remove the async/await?

Comment: @Rena because it is Rider/Resharper bug involving Primary Ctors + async methods. It is better to be addressed there.

Comment: Hi @Guru Stron, I test it in my visual studio without Resharper. Yes it actually have the value if I do like what you did `var localCopy = context; `, the context is null but the localCopy contains value.

Comment: @Rena yes, found issue for VS too (added it to the answer). Again, it is only representational issue in the debug view and the code actually works.

Comment: @jeb changed wording a bit.